# Devise Forgot password in bootstrap modal in a Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise, bootstrap-modal

I'm building a small app in Rails 4. I'm using devise for authentication.

I want to set up my signin in a popup/popover window. I have used bootstrap modal to achieve that. I have followed this link to successfully achieve that.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app

The following is my code

**application.html**

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-right">
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
         <div id="loggedinuser"> <%= current_user.email %>. Not you? </div>
         <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
      <% else %>
         <li><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-small btn-info">Log IN</a></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<%= form_for(:user, :url => session_path(:user)) do |f| %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter email' %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter password' %>
      <%= f.submit 'Sign in', class: 'btn btn-block btn-info' %>
 <% end %>
 <%= link_to content_tag(:small, 'Forgot your password?'), new_password_path(:user) %> 
</div>
```

The problem is with forgot password link. It takes me to password change path out of the modal popover.

Is there any way I can open it in the same modal replacing the content?

I saw the same question was asked here before but no one answered.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878494/devise-forgot-password-popover-modal

I hope someone could help me this time.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a button or form that hits a custom action in your controller (say `forgot_password`).

```
def forgot_password
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Then create a js view template named `forgot_password.js.erb` in the view folder for that controller. Put something like this in the template:

```
$("#your-modal-body-id").html("<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'forgot_password') %>");
```

Make sure you give your modal body the matching id as in your js view template.

Create your `forgot_password` partial as you like.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I tried a different approach to it yesterday. I included both the forms in the modal and used javascript to hide and show respective forms. It is working fine. But which approach is better? Yours or mine? I'm a bit new to all this.

Comment: I actually prefer your approach if there is nothing to pass back from the server (sounds like its the case)

Comment: If you could, Can you please help me with another question of mine which I have been struggling for a long time. here is the link for that quetion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400380/ruby-on-rails-remember-the-previously-selected-state-data-when-going-back